# Trigger SWF workflow when an object gets uploaded to S3 in JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-swf

I am using the AWS Flow Framework in JAVA to build a workflow. Ideally I would like to run the workflow when any object gets uploaded to S3.

Is there any way to capture the event from S3 using Java? It would be great if someone can point me to an example where they use JAVA to capture event notifications from S3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to start wf when file gets uploaded to s3. But S3 supports sending notifications when a file is added to your bucket. 
You can have either a sqs subscribed to the notification and then poll that queue and start the wf when you receive the message 
Or you can have a lambda function run every time a file is uploaded into the bucket that will start your wf.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit, I am aware of SQS but I want to use SNS to trigger my workflow. I believe that SNS has an option to send a HTTP Request , is it possible to capture that HTTP request and trigger a workflow?
I believe lambda supports JavaScript as of now, I am trying to code in Java.

Comment: You will need to host a rest end point that will listen to the notification and then start the workflow. There is no direct way to start wf based on sns notification